# How can I format an iPod touch (5th gen)?

Tags: usb, unix, ipod

I want to use Ubuntu 20.04, not a Mac or Windows os to format my iPod. It is a 5th generation iPod touch that I want to reset. I don't care about recovering/downloading the data, I simply want to be able to reset it (I have forgot the passcode). I have found many threads about this topic, but all are many years old and not very helpful. I have tried using itunes under wine, but I simply get a black screen when I run it.

The output of lsusb is as follows:

```
...
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 05ac:12aa Apple, Inc. iPod Touch 5.Gen [A1421]
...
```

`fdisk -l` only shows a few `loopx` devices and `nvme0n1` devices.